# Youtube API: Get videos from autogenerated channels (like Music)

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to get the videos from autogenerated channels (like this one https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/videos) directly, without having to access all the playlists?

Using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&key=... gives me 0 items.

Answer (score 0):

> Gives me 0 Items

If you mean running the following exactly

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&key=
```

Returns the following error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

That is because you have neglected to add an API key on the end.

Try testing in the [query explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&maxResults=25&_h=1&) this seams to return quite a few no idea if its all of them.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&maxResults=25&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

returns

```
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 786,
  "resultsPerPage": 25
 },
```

This apears to return a list of the playlists only for this user.

**Update**:

If you try and only request videos for this user you get 0 returned.  This is not the case for any other user which i have tested.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This leads me to believe that it is not possible to retrieve the videos for an autogenerated channel.  I recommend either logging this as a bug or adding it as a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B).  Personally i think its more a feature request.

Comment: i have the api key added, the full call looks like this: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&pageToken=\(pageToken)&key={key}

Comment: the problem is that it returns all the playlists, but i want just these videos https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/videos